# How to fix fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution undefined

Tags: ios, firebase, fastlane, firebase-cli

I'm trying to setup CI-CD for firebase app distribution on my local system.

`fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution` plugin can't be found.

```
Error loading plugin 'fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution': cannot load such file -- fastlane/plugin/firebase_app_distribution
+-------------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+
|                               Used plugins                               |
+-------------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+
| Plugin                                    | Version   | Action           |
+-------------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+
| fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution | undefined | No actions found |
+-------------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you install this Plugin with `fastlane add_plugin fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution`? Or try to execute: `sudo fastlane install_plugins`. Seems like others have the same issue: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution/issues/15

Comment: Yes. `sudo fastlane install_plugins` worked for installing. But, when I run `bundle exec fastlane testFlightRelease` it throws same error.

Comment: If you use bundle, use it consistently for every Fastlane related call: `bundle exec fastlane install_plugins`

Comment: tried that. Didn't help

Comment: @SagarKothari I am facing a pretty similar issue. did you find out the solutions? mine problem happens only on CI (github actions)

Answer (score 26):

Looks like some kind of file permission issue under Catalina, so chmod might help.
But you can also install `fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution` in gem's `USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` (`gem env` will tell you where it is).

Uninstall the gem from the default dir:

```
sudo gem uninstall fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution
```

Install in user dir:

```
gem install fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution --user-install
```

Comment: this is the correct answer and work with me and also found it in fastlane issues 

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution/issues/15

Comment: On macos, if you see `Gem 'fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution' is not installed` then try the uninstall command again without `sudo`. The `install` then worked for me, installing the latest version of the plugin.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you @Balaz.

Try this. I think this will solve the issue.

sudo chmod -R a+r /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution-0.1.4

I had the same issue.

Comment: This problem seems to be on macOS Catalina

Answer (score 6):

For me simply updating the Fastlane and then updating the plugins worked

```
bundle update fastlane
fastlane update_plugins
```

Comment: Works every time! :D My tip to Stackoverflow newbies, upvote the answers that help you. Because there will come a time when you will experience the same problem and you'd know what answer did help you when you first encountered such problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install plugin again. Command:

   ```
   fastlane add_plugin firebase_app_distribution
   ```

> more info:
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/ios/distribute-fastlane

2. If instillation does not help try to run

   ```
   bundle install
   ```
3. And the run your lane.

Comment: I started experiencing this issue after updating fastlane.  Reinstalling the plugin seemed to work for me.

Comment: This step worked for me but required moving the Gemfile.lock file first.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, Fastlane is not up to date. Might need to check fastlane version and update it

```
bundle update fastlane
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter and Github Actions for Android:**

If you are setting up Github Actions for a Flutter project for android and run into this error in one of your steps, see the work flow below:

```
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
      LANG: en_US.UTF-8
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1

      - name: Setup Fastlane
        working-directory: ./android  # <-- Make sure you have this
        run: bundle install

      - name: Run Fastlane
        working-directory: ./android. # <-- Make sure you have this
        run: bundle exec fastlane android [lane name].
```

Make sure to setup the ruby/setup-ruby@v1 action correctly depending on your project. see the doc: https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby

In my case I have not specified the ruby version because I am using the .ruby-version file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use this cmd to add the firebase_app_distribution plugin if you are using Fastlane.

```
bundle exec fastlane add_plugin firebase_app_distribution
```